# Closed port when tunneling HTTP over ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, amazon-sns

I'm developing an application which will use AWS's SNS service to receive notifications over HTTP.

As I am developing the application locally and have no control of our company firewall, I am attempting to tunnel HTTP connections from an external EC2 host to my local machine for the purposes of testing.

Everything looks fine when verifying the connection from the EC2 host itself, however the port is closed when examined externally.

My local application is on port 2222. I have executed the following command on my local machine to establish the proxy:

```
ssh -i myCredentials.pem ec2-user@myserver.com -R 2222:localhost:2222
```

Where `myserver.com` points to an EC2 instance. SSH'ing to the EC2 instance, I can successfully connect to my application via the tunnel, and `nmap` displays the following:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00055s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
2222/tcp open  EtherNet/IP-1
```

However when I run `nmap` against the EC2 instance from my local machine, the port is closed:

```
Nmap scan report for xxxxxx
Host is up (0.24s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
2222/tcp closed EtherNet/IP-1
```

The security group assigned to the server is allowing TCP traffic on ports 2222 on 0.0.0.0/0 and `iptables` isn't running on the server.

What do I need to do on the EC2 end to make this port open to the outside world?

Comment: edit your security profile?

Comment: The security group is already accepting inbound TCP traffic on port 2222 from 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Sorry, must have skipped that part.  If you start up another EC2 maybe a spot instance, is it open?

Comment: The previous EC2 instance was an Amazon Linux AMI. I just created a (non-spot) Ubuntu server and it has the same issue. I suspect I may be missing something fundamental in the whole tunnelling process.

Comment: I was trying to rule out whether it has anything to do with your firewall.  If you have two EC2's can you achieve a successful nmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tunnelling command is correct, however in order for SSH to bind to the wildcard address, the following setting is required in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote server:

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

Once this is added, restart `sshd` and the tunnelling will work as desired provided no firewalls are in the way.